# Jenkins publish reports fails with ClassNotFoundException: org.dom4j.DocumentException

Tags: junit, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Has anyone run into the error below?  I am trying to publish some JUnit Reports in Jenkins and am getting the following error.  The JUnit target runs fine and the reports are created, but the publishing step is failing with this error:

```
ERROR: Failed to archive test reports
java.io.IOException: remote file operation failed: /jenkins/workspace/test_job at hudson.remoting.Channel@715c51c7:Slave01
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:910)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:887)
    at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitParser.parse(JUnitParser.java:87)
    at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitResultArchiver.parse(JUnitResultArchiver.java:121)
    at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitResultArchiver.perform(JUnitResultArchiver.java:133)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:714)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:663)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1713)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:231)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Remote call on Slave01 failed
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:731)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:903)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/DocumentException
    at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitParser$ParseResultCallable.invoke(JUnitParser.java:117)
    at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitParser$ParseResultCallable.invoke(JUnitParser.java:90)
    at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2462)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:328)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dom4j.DocumentException (WebAppClassLoader=Jenkins v1.557@6c7e6b26 did not find class file)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteClassLoader$ClassLoaderProxy.fetch2(RemoteClassLoader.java:727)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteClassLoader$ClassLoaderProxy.fetch4(RemoteClassLoader.java:777)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteClassLoader$ClassLoaderProxy.fetch3(RemoteClassLoader.java:784)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2922.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.perform(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:299)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:328)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:46)
    ... 4 more
Build step 'Publish JUnit test result report' changed build result to FAILURE
```

Comment: gettings similar in that phase but on another class: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hudson/tasks/junit/JUnitParser$ParseResultCallable`

Comment: Having the exact same issue. Have you been able to solve this?